# MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo PathName Not Accepted

Tags: msmq, javascript

I am using MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo with jscript on Windows 7 (the latest MSMQ version).  This is being run on a domain joined computer. For some reason unknown to me, it just will not accept the PathName I give it (which is in an [acceptable format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706083%28VS.85%29.aspx)).  Here is the code:

```
var qi = new ActiveXObject ("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo");
qi.PathName = "FormatName:Direct=OS:mycomputer\\Private$\\myqueue";
```

I know this PathName works, because I use the exact same path in c#, and *that* works:

```
queue = new MessageQueue("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:" + contollerName + "\\Private$\\" + queueName);
```

When the code "qi.Open()" in the jscript code attempts to execute, it returns this error message: *The queue path name specified is invalid.*

Has anyone else run into this?  Ideas?  Comments?  Suggestions?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong parameter for accessing a remote private queue:

**MSMQQueueInfo.PathName**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707110(v=VS.85).aspx
"However, the MSMQQueueInfo.**FormatName** property must be set with a direct format name to open a remote private queue."

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your fast response!  You are correct, there is a FormatName property that I completely did not see.  I used that property and now the test works!  Thanks a bunch!